# I want to use pandas2ri in JUPYTER but tzlocal issue?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, jupyter, rpy2

Everytime I try to import the pandas2ri in jupyter, python interface:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-cc52694d111a> in <module>()
----> 1 from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

/Users/sondosayyash/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py in <module>()
     21 import numpy
     22 import pytz
---> 23 import tzlocal
     24 import warnings
     25 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tzlocal'
```

I tried to use

```
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
```

but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

I've already installed tzlocal and it is on my computer.  When I import pandas2ri on ipython, there is no problem.. the problem only occurs when calling in the jupyter environment.

this is the message I get when I try to install tzlocal again:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. 

Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tzlocal) (2017.2)
```

Comment: It seems this `tzlocal` library is missing from your system. The error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tzlocal'` says you have to [install `tzlocal`](https://pypi.org/project/tzlocal/). You could use `pip install tzlocal` to install it.

Comment: @edesz it's already been installed, and works perfectly fine when running ipython on my computer.  It's when I call it in the jupyter environment that I get this error message.

Comment: Hmmm, the problem was also discussed here ([1](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/463/pandas-import-error-using-rmagic), [2](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/468/rpy2-cant-find-installed-pandas-package)) but apparently was fixed in [`rpy2 2.9.4`](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/index.html). What is your version of `rpy2`?

Comment: When I try to do the following command: pip install rpy2 --upgrade, I get this error:
    `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/47/ql6bz49x0ygdpc6nmcs6c6r80000gn/T/pip-install-lMR_fB/rpy2/ `
However, when I type    `python3 --version`    , I get python 3.6.0
If I just type    `python --version`     it will list python 2.7
perhaps this is the issue? I'm not sure what to do. @edesz

Comment: What is the kernel version  in I the jupyter notebook? If the kernel is listed as python2 then use `pip`. Otherwise you might need `pip3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue when running rpy2 in Jupyter. I did not have the package installed previously. I just installed the package and the error went away. You can try installing the package again to see if it helps resolve your issue.

```
pip install tzlocal
```

I must add that I am using Python 3.6.8 not 2.7

Answer (score 4):

If using `conda`:

```
conda install tzlocal
```

worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as yours. It turns out that my local lib did not have the tzlocal package. So I installed the package through Anaconda prompt:

```
pip install tzlocal
```

And the issue is gone.